# Why did Palpatine decide to take over the Republic?

Tags: star-wars

I remember someone told me (or maybe I read it somewhere) that there was a big incoming alien invasion to the Republic.

**Palpatine** learned about it and realized that a peaceful Republic could not hold against it so he decided to perform a coup on the Republic so as to have a "strong" leadership with a huge military able to defend from alien invasion.

Is this correct, and why Palpatine decided to go for the dark side?

Was he a normal Jedi first?

Comment: "big incoming alien invasion to the Republic." Do you possibly mean the Yuuzhan Vong
http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Yuuzhan_Vong?

Comment: Not sure, I don't remember. The point was that Palpatine was making an evil think (coup) for a greater good (save galaxy)..

Comment: @hammythepig Palpatine was long dead by the time of the Yuuzhan Vong War

Comment: @gobernador yes, but I was wondering if OP was referring to him maybe knowing about their future strike.  It's obvious he was not alive to see them.

Comment: Pick up the Darth Plagueis book. It pretty much has Palpatine's entire back story.

Comment: @gobernador - but that is what the vision was.

Comment: The commonly accepted view is that his vision was indeed of the Yuuzhan Vong.

Comment: Isn't there a similar argument made in the KOTOR series? That the overarching big bad of the two games foresaw some kind of invasion so he sicced Darth Revan on the Republic to force them to toughen up?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Darth Plagueis did foresee the invasion and believed that he could stop it with a strong military under his rule.  The entire plot is actually the plan of Plagueis, Palpatine's Master.

Palpatine was leaning towards the dark side early in his life.  Plagueis found him and nurtured that and trained him to be a Sith.  The story plays out in the novel [Darth Plagueis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/034551128X)

Comment: Were Plagueis's intentions noble? Or did they see protecting the galaxy from an invasion as a way to permanently cement Sith power over the galaxy?

Comment: Probably Darth Plagueis and friends thought intentions were noble. I guess this is classic dilemma about necessary evil...

Comment: @DougT - No...  The plan was about being an immortal ruler of the galaxy.  The greatest downfall of the Sith is they are never satisfied with the little things...

Comment: I do not remember anything from the Darth Plagueis novel about this. Any quotes or sources to back it up?

Comment: @Domenic - Any quote would be spoilers which I worked hard to answer with out giving too many away.  The vision is in the first few chapters... possibly even the prologue.

Answer (score 9):

Palpatine was Sith from his beginnings. He was born and raised on Naboo into aristocracy. He grew to hate his parents and family and at that time caught the eye of Darth Plagueis, who eventually became his master. His rise to Supreme Chancellor and later Emperor was a long and very elaborate plot of his. He was never a Jedi.